# Nested if statements with or condition

Tags: javascript, logic, pseudocode

I have some js code that currently looks something like this:

```
var test
//do some stuff with the var
if (test === "A" || test === "B" || test === "C") {
    if (test === "A" || test === "B") {
        //do some small stuff
    } 
    //do some more complex stuff
}
```

Is there a nicer way to write this to avoid the duplicated condition? It seems basic, I know, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado 
I think that the question implies that there may also be "D" so in addition to grouping the conditions there is nothing else to do, perhaps understanding the context could be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could assign a variable to avoid having to write the complex condition multiple times:

```
let a_or_b = test === 'A' || test === 'B';
if (a_or_b || test === 'C') {
    if (a_or_b) {
        // do some small stuff
    }
    // do more complex stuff
}
```

or

```
let a_or_b = false;
if (test === 'A' || test === 'B') {
    // do some small stuff
    a_or_b = true;
}
if (a_or_b || test === 'C') {
    // do more complex stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, just set the duplicated condition into as a variable, hope it help you

```
var test;
var isAOrB = (test === "A" || test === "B");
if (isAOrB || test === "C") {
if (isAOrB) {
    //do some small stuff
} 
//do some more complex stuff
```

}